# Is it possible to download a torrent file completely and quickly with no uploading, but let the file be uploaded by other users after it has finished?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Is it possible to download a torrent file completely and quickly with no uploading? And then after seed the file to be uploaded by other users?

I'm finding that the downloading process is incredibly slow while downloading some torrent file with incredibly high upload rates. Is it possible to speed up the downloading rate by cutting off uploading completely until the file has been completely downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/), you can limit the upload speeds. The lowest I can see is about 5kb/s.

Comment: You can do it with utorrent too> but will decreasing the upload speed make the downloading faster?

Comment: @B-Ballerl - That depends on your connection.  Odds are, no, it will make zero difference. (And it might hurt your share ratio to boot, which is a good way to get blacklisted from a tracker.)

Comment: Ahhhh Allright. False Hope for me anyways. Thanks everyone

Comment: Decreasing your upload can actually slow down your download.  Some programs can be set to not share with leachers who aren't sharing, or aren't sharing a lot.

Comment: Limiting upload speed in uTorrent will also limit the download speed proportionately to the effect of stopping the download (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

If your bottom line is to speed up the downloading rate, limiting upload to 5 KB/s is typically not a good idea. I would suggest:

1. Check your upload bandwidth, e.g. www.speedtest.net, www.bandwidthplace.com
2. Limit upload bandwith to half of the value above.

The reason for this is that your peers my not upload to you if your client does not upload. Unless you only use bit torrent to download Ubuntu ISO etc.